# How can I calculate the "average" or "median" result between a number of MultiLine Strings?

Tags: qgis, vector, linestring

So I have a number (let's say 12) of multiline strings representing something that changes over time, like forest borders or shorelines. I want to create a single line that is the result of the average or median calculation of those 12 strings. So if I have 1 ML String of a feature per month, I can calculate the average of those MLs for that year.

[image]

Comment: By "multiline strings" do you mean "multipart lines"?

Comment: It's an ESRI shapefile containing Line (MultiLineString)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123731/create-mean-line-from-multiple-lines-using-qgis