# create heatmap from coordinates

Tags: line, heat-map

computer science student here, haven't done much in GIS, just trying to finish a project for a class.

What I have is a CSV of origin/destination points as co-ordinates (longitude and latitude)

what I want to do is to create a heatmap of the routes, similar to a traffic heatmap that you see on google maps.

ie. I want more frequented pieces of road to be red, and less frequented to be green. not just the more frequented origins/destinations, thats trivial.

what's the easiest way to do this? I have experience with python, java and matlab.

I was wondering if there is a free software that could do it straight from the CSV? or maybe a python module?

edit:
since im using just a CSV of origin/destination points, I believe it is not a duplicate, since the referenced post used GPS tracks, which is quite different information.

Comment: Your "routes" and the duplicate's "tracks" are both line features and whether they come from a GPS or a CSV does not seem to be enough to separate the techniques involved in creating a "heat map" from either.  If you do not know how to create line features from a CSV then that would be a different question, and one that I would expect to have already been asked and answered here.  If not, feel free to ask that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to create heatmaps straight from the CSV data, assuming you have latitude and longitudes. You can use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and follow the QGIS tutorial on [Creating Heatmaps](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html).

If you have GPS tracks or just want to use another way of making a heatmap for line features, you should take a look at [Creating polyline-based "heatmap" from GPS tracks?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/how-to-create-a-polyline-based-heatmap-from-gps-tracks).

Comment: looking at the tutorial, it looked like a heatmap of discrete points.

what I want is a heatmap of routes, given my origin and destination points.

ie. i'll give a list of pairs, (origin x,y ; destination x, y) 
and i want a heatmap of the routes.

so my first entry would be LA to san fransisco, and i would want a route connecting those two. then my second entry, LA to fresno, and a route connecting those two cities, etc. Then the more frequented pieces of route to be darker than the less frequented pieces of route.

is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: also, im looking for the general name of the thing I described. Making a heatmap of routes, not just the points.

Comment: @mac5 the second link does show how to make heatmaps for lines, but as polygeo said you'll have to makes lines from the cordinates that you have, you should be able to do that in QGIS.

If you have the number the frequency of the usage of routes as an attribute in you data, then it's just a simple matter of assigning the symbology (the color of the lines) based on that frequency.