# Create line heatmap with QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, heat-map, movement-data, strava

I have loaded my bike tours as .gpx files into QGIS.

[image]

It already looks quite nice but I was wondering if it might be possible to create something similar to the strava heatmap with tools of QGIS.

[image]

I have tried to generate points along the lines and use kernel density but it just does not look nice as a raster layer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/creating-polyline-based-heatmap-from-gps-tracks?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how looks like my *strava* routes, rendered in QGIS. What I do is to merge all gpx tracks (otherwise you should change blending mode one by one) into a single file and then, into the **Layer Properties > Symbology tab**, choose an appropriate colour, then opening the layer rendering options to select **Screen** as the blending type for the **Features** parameter while you keep the normal rendering for the Layer parameter.

Hope this helps.
Cheers,

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with Strava, but in QGIS you can use a combination of blending modes and draw effects to get a raster-like feel, similar to the image above.

[image]

You can find both of them in the Style Properties of your layer (*blending modes are under Layer Rendering*).

Comment: For more examples see: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2017/02/carto-tips-using-blend-modes-opacity-levels/