# Increase the size of overlapping lines in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, geojson, qgis-3

In QGIS I have a layer that is a MultiLineString that has many overlapping lines, which represent driving routes around the city which are generated using OSRM.

My data looks something like

```
[
[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h]],
[[y,z],[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h]],
[[e,f],[g,h],[i,j],[k,l]]
]
```

where some segments are only recorded once, some twice, and some many more times (up to thousands of times).

**How can I increase the width (line thickness) of segments of the routes based on the number of times they are overlapped?**

I have a working solution using the JavaScript libraries OpenLayers and Turf but the solution is inefficient and cannot scale. See below for an example of the desired effect.

[image: example]

Answers that involve re-formatting the data or working in Python are within my scope.

Comment: Make sure each segment is a separate feature. Install the refFunctions plugin. Use data-defined settings for line width with the function `intersecting_geom_count()`.

Comment: Would you be satisfied increasing the *brightness* of overlapping lines? Have a look at this Q&A about creating a "heatmap" of lines:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286082/create-line-heatmap-with-qgis

Comment: @csk, no, I specifically would like to increase the width. I will try the instructions from your previous comment tonight.