# Displaying frequently traveled routes?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, route

How can I display frequently traveled routes?

I think this has been asked before in a question I am unable to relocate which was about how to display multiple overlapping routes on a map, so that frequently traveled routes (with many overlaps) are bright, and single routes are dim. I believe they were trying to re-create an effect from a map they had found elsewhere, and there was an image of that map included in the question.

**The answer** used transparency and blending modes to create a beautiful effect, where overlapping lines appeared to glow.

The solution looked something like this, except that the lines followed roads in the basemap. They may also have been categorized with a red-yellow-green color scheme.

[image]

The basemap in the solution (and possibly also in the question) was a dark grayscale map, similar to ESRI Gray (dark) or CartoDB Dark Matter.

Comment: [something like this?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/286082/55203)?

Comment: Should I delete this question now? I'm not sure if it's useful to anyone other than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion on [Creating polyline-based “heatmap” from GPS tracks?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/42224/48394) has approaches based on GeoTools/GeoServer, Mapbox/TileMill, umap, QGIS, ArcGIS, and other technologies.

Comment: Actually the one i was looking for was [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286082/create-line-heatmap-with-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I was able to get to it from the one you suggested, because they're linked. I favorited both of them so I can find them again in the future. Thank you!