# Visualising road segments as heatmap

Tags: leaflet, visualisation, heat-map, mapbox-gl-js

I have some data on frequency of different road segments, and need to visualise it as a `heatmap`. Is there some utility/plugin for `Mapbox` or `Leaflet` which does this kind of visualisation. I am only able to find `Leaflet` plugins for visualising points as `heatmap`.

My current approach is to convert the frequency into a colour range, and then put it in `GeoJSON`. But it suffers from the problem where I can't assign proper weights to the `polyline`. I need the line to exactly overlap the road (proper width and following the road curve), so that it seems like highlighting the road.

Another approach could be breaking the line into multiple points, encoding frequency in them and making a `heatmap` out of that. But that would be too artificial, and I think that there should be a better elegant way out there.

Comment: [@arpanmangal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/123725/arpanmangal) Have you already checked [this article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/creating-polyline-based-heatmap-from-gps-tracks)?

Comment: @TarasDubrava none of them exactly meets the requirements. Most of them are not for `mapbox` or `leaflet`. I found only one, but that is a bit outdated, and I don't think it is plotting the line such as to cover the exact width of the road