# QGIS Heat map Agent

Tags: qgis, python

So I have a city lets say London and I've imported the location of houses in London and roads next to those houses and calculated the nearest distance point in meters and have it as a layer.

Now my assignment is to program an agent(??) that will begin from a random position at the map and go through the map by avoiding locations with high values of distance or air quality (I've imported this also for London).

In the end I should make it like a heat map with calculation of whole path of the agent.

I cannot find an example of someone doing this on google, maybe I'm searching something wrongly or using the wrong terminology but in general does anyone understand how would I approach this problem properly

Comment: like this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/creating-polyline-based-heatmap-from-gps-tracks

Comment: It looks similar but I think my task is more advanced since my agent should involve parameter like distance and air quality? Probably this should be done in python?